# the proper way cleaning spam from database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

for my WordPress site, I am cleaning my database from spam, which was somehow inserted there, but my site is working regardless. I opened phpmyadmin, and saw spam in wp_posts… so in phpmyadmin, I open the table, go to the tab that says browse, go over the posts one by one, find spam posts and just hit delete and those posts are physically removed, right?

but what about the table called wp_postmeta? don't all the posts in wp_posts have a corresponding entry in wp_postmeta? if so, if I delete spam posts from posts table will it be a problem or it is ok?

even if it is ok, the meta for the spam post will still remain in postmeta table if I delete just the post from wp_post. so is there a better way to clean faster and both? I didn't touch anything yet. I want to know first

Answer (score 0):

The best option would probably be to find and delete the spam content from the admin panel itself. Then when you delete the post that contains spam, it will also cleanup the corresponding meta data.

Otherwise, I suppose you could manually match up the ID's between the two tables and delete it directly from the database.

Comment: from admin panel it is not possible. the hackers made those posts in such a way, that i can not see them in admin panel (in which way i wonder, which may be useful to filter them at once instead of looking for them one by one in table)